# How to remove Cerber3 ransomware and decrypt .cerber3 files

Tags: encryption

Recently in my PC all the immages and document files are changed to weired name with extension .cerber3. I found in internet that it is a latest version of cerber ransomeware but I can not able to find any solution to decrypt that files. If I can not find the solution then I will lost my important photos and files because I do not have any backup anywhere of such files.
[image]

Comment: I hate to say this, but the easiest way is always to recover from backups - no one ever does it until they get burnt. In this case, you're likely going to have to wait till someone reverse engineers the malware. Paying the ransom dosen't mean getting your files back and encourages this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

> ... at this time it’s not possible to recover the files encrypted by the Cerber3 ransomware.

Source: [Remove Cerber3 ransomeware - Malwaretips](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-cerber3-virus/)

Comment: I do not want hear such answer If you have solution then please provide otherwise don't post any answer.

Comment: @HardipsinhJadeja Just because you don't like the answer doesn't make it wrong. It is a correct and perfectly valid answer.